# Restoring an option at the end of a function in zsh

Tags: shell, shell-script, zsh, function

I'm writing a zsh shell function (as opposed to a script) where I would really like the `extended_glob` option to be enabled. But since the function runs in the caller's context, I don't want to clobber their settings.

What I'd like to do is conditionally enabled `extended_glob` as long as I need it and then restore it to the user's option. Is there any way to check whether an option is enabled in zsh?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`local_options` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-LOCALOPTIONS) to automatically restore options when the function exits. This would only be appropriate if your function does not make any *other* option changes that you intend to persist after the function has finished.

Thus, you could write your function like this:

```
do_something() {
  setopt local_options extended_glob
  ⋮
}
```

If you have some other option that you want to persist after the function has returned, you can use the `options` associative array (from the [`zsh/parameter` module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module)) to easily check and manipulate individual options:

```
do_something() {
  local eg=$options[extended_glob]
  setopt extended_glob
  ⋮
  options[extended_glob]=$eg
}
```

If this module is not available in your installation, then you can use the `-o` [test](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions):

```
do_something() {
  local eg=no
  [[ -o extended_glob ]] && eg=
  setopt extended_glob
  ⋮
  setopt ${eg}extended_glob
}
```